# How can I configure the fields for a job in hudson automatically via script or command line

Tags: java, maven, svn, hudson

I'm trying to find a way to configure some fields of some jobs hudson. so I do not need to open all jobs, and for that, after setting the fields in a first job, the same fields of the other jobs would also be configured automatically. 
but unfortunately I can not find any possible solution ... 
if someone can help at least giving me a start so I start I would greatly appreciate it.

best regards.

Comment: Show us what you have tried

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the [Job DSL plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Job+DSL+Plugin).  A more lightweight solution could be the [Jenkins CLI](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Jenkins+CLI).